# Azure Functions: Why do I see two w3wp processes in Kudu?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kudu

I have a single `Function` app running on Azure. When I go to Kudu, I see two `w3wp.exe` procceses. Can somebody tell me why I see two instead of one? Also, what does `scm` mean?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process labeled as SCM is for running Kudu, the other one is for the Function App.